# Angular JS is Giving an Undefined Function Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a back end application that shows listings similar to a phone book. I have some filters that it sorts by and pagination as well.  The app loads all the data first and then the filtering and pagination is essentially done instantly.  I can't figure out what the problem is here.   From online and my book everything appears to be OK.  This is the error I get:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at new <anonymous> (http://local.poha.com/js/ang.js:21:10)

var listingsApp = angular.module('listingsApp', []);

listingsApp.controller('pageController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.GetListings();  <--- line 21

    $scope.GetListings = function () {

        //function code here

    }

})

<html ng-app="listingsApp">
...
<body ng-controller="pageController">

    <div class="pagination">Page: <span ng-repeat="page in pages">
        <a href="" ng-click="GoToPage($index)">{{$index + 1}}</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <table id="updateTable" width="2000" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" border="0">

    ...

        <tr ng-repeat="listing in allListings">
            <td>{{listing.id}}</td>
            <td>{{listing.name}}</td>
            <td>{{listing.address}}</td>
            <td>{{listing.city}}</td>
            <td>{{listing.state}}</td>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call the function $scope.GetListings() before it's defined.

try :

```
   $scope.GetListings = function () {
        //function code here
   }
   $scope.GetListings();
```

Comment: Wow, I did not know that, different from PHP.